# How to display tables from back-end (Mysql) to front-end Net-Beans?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-7

How do you display the table values stored in the back-end which is MySQL to your design page in Net-Beans?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. As it is, this question involves so many different aspects of programming. If you have a specific problem, describe it here and add your code, we'll all be glad to try to help you. Otherwise you should try to break your requirement down to simpler tasks, tackle them one by one and maybe ask questions here about specific problems you may run into.

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch the values,store them in session and get that session in your front end like in html or jsp.for eg

```
ArrayList<String> list =new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
```

in your back end you can set it like
session.setAttribute("list",list);

And in your front end get it as

```
ArrayList<String> list=(ArrayList<String>)session.getAttribute("list")
```

if you are using any mvc framework like spring then jsp provides its jstl tags where list will be directly populated by binding your view with  model class.you can refer some tutorial for that.